# create a dictionary( MAP ) from 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary

Lets assume I have arrays of Strings ( but it should work aslo with array of numbers).

I would like to create a Map object over them with one's value of the 2 as keys and the others as values, but basically to establish a relationship. After that next step would be create a Map from 2 Array of Objects, but this is a bit more complicated.

Unfortunately my approach so far isn't working( since few hours try make it working), as I get for the second value the *Map Iterator* either for Arrays of Objects

```
let pairsMap = new Map(); 
let productsMap = new Map();
let engWords = ['house','gift','zoo','tidy','flat','to play',' to see','boy','ice cream']
let itaWords = ['casa','regalo','zoo','ordinato','appartamento','giocare','guardare','ragazzo','gelato'] 
let pairsMap = new Map(); 
let productsMap = new Map();
let products = [
{
  name: "chair",
  inventory: 5,
  unit_price: 45.99,
  client:'MG Gmbh'
},
{
  name: "table",
  inventory: 10,
  unit_price: 123.75,
  client : "XYZ"
},
{
  name: "sofa",
  inventory: 2,
  unit_price: 399.50,
  client : "MongoDB"
}];

let clients  =[
 {
     name:"MG Gmbh",
     address: 'Linen street',
     country: 'Germany'
 },
 {
     name:'XYZ',
     address:'Mongomery street',
     country: 'USA'
 },
 {
     name:'MongoDB',
     address: 'NoSQL road',
     country: 'UK'
 },
 {
    name:'Zeppelin',
    address: 'lienestraße',
    country: 'Germany'
}];

for( val in engWords){

      const nk =  engWords[val];
      engWords.forEach(function(element) {
      const v = pairsMap.values();
      pairsMap.set(nk,v);  
    } )
   }

 for (let [b, z] of pairsMap){
     console.log(b, " -> ", z)
 }

 function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
      return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
   var key = obj[property];
     if (!acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = [];
     }
     acc[key].push(obj);
     return acc;
     }, {});
  }


let clients_name = console.log(groupedClients);


 for( val in groupedClients){

       const nk =  groupedClients[val];
       products.forEach(function(element) {
           const v = productsMap.values();
           productsMap.set(nk,v);   

       } )
   }
```

This is the result I would like to get( from engWords and itaWords)

```
house  ->  casa 
gift  ->  regalo 
zoo  ->  zoo 
tidy  ->  ordinato 
flat  ->  appartamento 
to play  ->  giocare 
to see  ->  guardare 
boy  ->  ragazzo 
ice cream  ->  gelato
```

Comment: What is the final result you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where I was missing, at least for the 2 Arrays, not using the right "index" for the "value" of the Map, so this way worked:

```
for( val in engWords){

   const nk =  engWords[val];
       engWords.forEach(function(element) {
       pairsMap.set(nk,itaWords[val]);  
   } )
}

for (let [b, z] of pairsMap){
    console.log(b, " -> ", z)
}
```

and doing that change also for the Arrays of object worked as well but not on the
 using the grouped by name:

```
for( val in clients){

   const nk =  clients[val];
      products.forEach(function(element) {
      productsMap.set(nk,products[val]);  
   } )
 }
```

Though the order for the relationship remain that of the order in the original 
 arrays, so the order is still not dynamic.

[UPDATE]

I was able to compare for check if an element of an Array was also in the Map( another goal), and made a slightly modification of the above, but seems it sucks too much Chrome CPU, as from Chrome Task Manager my file took more then 109 % of GPU( browser), and seems so strange to me.

```
let m = ['casa','house']; 

Array.from(newMap.keys()).forEach((k, i) => {
    var values = newMap.get(k);
    for(let j = 0;j < m.length ; i++){
       if(m[i] == values){
           console.log(m[i]);
       }  
    }     
})
```